# Added SSL to EC2 but won't turn green

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

With AWS, I generated an SSL certificate for my site. In EC2 > Load Balancers > Listeners > dded
Load Balancer: HTTPS
Load Balancer port: 443
Instance protocol: HTTP
Instance port: 80
SSL Cert: The SSL I generated

The site works when I access it via https, but the 'https' doesn't turn green (and the padlock doesn't appear). Any reason why?

Thanks!

Comment: I presume you have [self signed certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate).  Is this the case?  Different browsers respond to a self signed cert differently.  If possible share your website address and we might be able to provide more info.

Comment: https://roshiclips.com/ - I ran a test on whynopadlock.com and it showed nothing is loaded insecurely. What's weird though is if I right click > view page source, it shows https green.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately this isn't an EC2 nor self signed certificate issue as [your certificate is good](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://roshiclips.com/).  It's important to use browser debug tools as they can often help you with the issue.  For example, in Chrome I get a bunch of

```
roshiclips.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://roshiclips.com/'
was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
'http://i.imgur.com/0zWOURf.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

and a few:

```
roshiclips.com/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://roshiclips.com/' was
loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure video 
'http://nba.cdn.turner.com/nba/big/video/2017/04/09/8669b068-3544-4cac-a863-58596304dba2.nba_1355868_1920x1080_5904.mp4'.
This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

So I'd start by making sure everything is loaded via HTTPS.  You've also got a few other issues with JavaScript and with a call to a websocket but those won't break the SSL part, just the operational part.

For reference, in Chrome, I went to the menu then "More Tools" -> "Developer Tools" to see the console.  This showed me the warnings and errors.

Comment: ah okay thank you! I'll work on that now. Quick question though, is it necessary that all content is loaded over https? What if I'm pulling content from other sites but they don't have it in https?

Comment: Then it will still be broken.  It's an all or nothing type of thing.  I can see that the imgur.com link is available in https as is but the video is not.  Unfortunately there isn't a way around this unless you're willing to run your own proxy.  But there may be legal issues with you serving content from a third party site and presenting as your own - I'm most definitely not a lawyer.  Technically though it is possible but a bit of a pain.